# Trying to Make a Div Sticky at certain position but an Uncaught TypeError broke other codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky, typeerror

I'm trying to make a div sticky while scrolling, and unstick at a certain height.I got the code below and edited it. It worked but an error in it affected other Jquery scripts from working. When I checked console for the error, I got this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined at HTMLDocument.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
    return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
  };

  var $el = $('#imgsticky');
  var $window = $(window);
  var top = $el.parent().position().top;

  $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
    var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 170;
    var visibleFoot = 970 - $window.scrollBottom();
    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

    if (scrollTop < top + 50) {
      $el.css({
        top: (top - scrollTop) + "px",
        bottom: "auto"
      });
    } else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
      $el.css({
        top: "auto",
        bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
      });
    } else {
      $el.css({
        top: 60,
        bottom: "auto"
      });
    }
  }).scroll();
});
```

How do I fix this please?

Comment: Can you please post the relevant HTML code as well so that we can take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the jQuery object contains any element before you try to get its `position`:

```
var parentEl = $el.parent();
var top =0;
if (parentEl.length) {
   top = parentEl.position().top;

}
```